# Non recursive fibonacci function

Tags: c++, fibonacci

I was trying to write a non recursive fibonacci function in C++. Here is my code for it:

```
int fib(const int num)
{
    std::vector<int> array{ 0, 1 };
    for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = (array[i - 1] + array[i - 2]);
    }
    return array[num];

}

int main()
{
    const int n = 10;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        cout << fib(i) << " ";
    }

}
```

The compiler gives me a "Debug Assertion Failed" Error with an expression that vector subscript out of range. Could you please tell me what is here wrong? All indexes seemed to be in vector's range...
Thanks!

Comment: You start the i variable from 2 (and goes to 10) and your vector has only two elements which means you re accessing an out of range array element

Comment: As an alternative you could set the size at creation of the vector, and then assign to index `0` and `1` for their values before you do the loop. Then all the indexes will be valid.

Comment: _"All indexes seemed to be in vector's range"_ how did you determine what the vector's range is?  I suspect that your problem lies with that determination, but you haven't described how you calculated what indexes would be valid for `std::vector<int> array{ 0, 1 };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized `array` with only two members, so only the indexes `0` and `1` are valid. Your loop goes from `2` to `n` which goes beyond the allocated bounds of the array when you do `array[i]`. To add a new element into a vector you should use `push_back()` instead. It will allocate new space in the array:

```
array.push_back(array[i - 1] + array[i - 2]);
```